# How MMU gets physical address of interrupt vector?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, mmu

When OS is executing some process and then interrupt occurs will there be entry created in page table? How MMU does virtual to physical address conversion of ISR when interrupt occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The processor uses the page tables for the currently running process. Those page tables should define the system address space range that will be the same for all process so it does not matter what process is running at that time.

Comment: Interrupts are normally switches context from User into System mode and system/kernel has it's own translation tables. That way you do not replicate kernel memory mappings in every process.

Answer (score 0):

> When OS is executing some process and then interrupt occurs will there be entry created in page table?

- What sort of interrupt are you asking about? Speculatively speaking interrupt handler could modify mmu page tables. Not likely that happens in real life though unless that's a page fault interrupt. You better have all used memory properly mapped.

> How MMU does virtual to physical address conversion of ISR when interrupt occurs?

- Absolutely the same way as for ANY other virtual-to-physical translations, via mmu page tables.